# Run-time error '3264' Access 2010 VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error, dao

I'm trying to create a new table with a VBA macro in Access 2010 to store some output and I am unable to do the basics of just creating said empty table below is the relevant code:

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim emptyTdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim rs, emptyRs As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld, emptyFld As DAO.Field
Dim fldnm As String
Dim fldv As Variant
Dim isEmptyField As Boolean



Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("AP")
Set emptyTdf = dbs.CreateTableDef("AP_Empty")
Set emptyFld = emptyTdf.CreateField("HID", dbText, 255)
dbs.TableDefs.Append emptyTdf
```

The last line sets off the run-time error. I've followed a few tutorials online using the DAO method to create tables and my code doesn't deviate, so I guess it is a syntactical gotcha that I've stumbled on.

Comment: Try to follow [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193203(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append your field to the TableDef before appending the TableDef itself:

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim emptyTdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim rs, emptyRs As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld, emptyFld As DAO.Field
Dim fldnm As String
Dim fldv As Variant
Dim isEmptyField As Boolean

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("AP")
Set emptyTdf = dbs.CreateTableDef("AP_Empty")
Set emptyFld = emptyTdf.CreateField("HID", dbText, 255)

'Append your created field.
emptyTdf.Fields.Append emptyFld

dbs.TableDefs.Append emptyTdf

'Just so your collections and the db window is refreshed.
dbs.TableDefs.Refresh
Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow
```